# django makemigrations ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.Falsedb'

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-crispy-forms, modulenotfounderror, django-bootstrap5

I am learning to use Django, and when trying to install Crispy Forms and running 'makemigrations,' I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 275, in _get_default_pk_class
    pk_class = import_string(pk_class_path)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.Falsedb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/src/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/src/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 156, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in tables
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 71, in __get__
    return self.fget(cls)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 32, in Migration
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 365, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 378, in _prepare
    opts._prepare(cls)
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 329, in _prepare
    pk_class = self._get_default_pk_class()
  File "/home/javier/Desktop/pd110/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 281, in _get_default_pk_class
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD refers to the module 'django.Falsedb.models.BigAutoField' that could not be imported.
```

I've performed migrations before without any issues. In my 'settings.py,' I have the following in the 'installed apps':

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'boletin',
]
```

boletin is my app name
My project tree structure is the following one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EupNw.jpg)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Django 4.2.7 and Crispy Forms in my virtual environment, but it didn't work. I would appreciate it if someone could provide me with some assistance because I'm just starting with Django and I haven't mastered it yet. Thank you, and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `django.db.models.BigAutoField` has become `django.Falsedb.models.BigAutoField` by mistake somewhere in your project.

Have a look in your `settings.py` file and make sure that `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` option is set correctly,

```py
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

The same setting is also set in the `apps.py` file for each of your installed apps. For example

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BooksConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "books"
```

Failing that do a global search in your code base for `Falsedb`.

Comment: This was the problem, I'm not sure when I changed it by mistake. When I set DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD back to the correct value, it got resolved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Provide the Models.py content that you tried to migrate to database..?

Seems like the problem lies with this statement 'django.Falsedb.models.BigAutoField'

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
# Other fields for your model
```